# First order logic issue with the truth and scope of quantifiers

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, quantifiers

I have two examples of universal and existential quantifiers that I have seen and that I cannot understand why they work:

1. $\exists x \forall y R(x,y)$
2. $\exists x \forall y(R(x,y) \iff x=y)$

They are both true of the following pairs:

$\langle1, 1\rangle$
$\langle1, 2\rangle$
$\langle1, 3\rangle$
$\langle1, 4\rangle$
$\langle1, 5\rangle$
$\langle2, 5\rangle$
$\langle4, 1\rangle$
$\langle5, 5\rangle$

Whereas it is trivial to figure out why 1) holds since it would hold for pairs $\langle1, 1...5\rangle$, example 2) is not as straightforward. The way I understand it is that:

*There is some $x$ where for all $y$ such that there is a pair relation of $x$ and $y$ is true iff $x$ equals $y$.*

But if I have, for example $x = 1$, and I iterate through the whole domain, it is clear that universal quantifier only holds for $R(x, y)$ but not for $x = y$ biconditionally. For $R(1, 1) \iff 1 = 1$ it is indeed true, but $R(1, 2) \iff 1 = 2$ is already false (second step of universal iteration).

Does this mean that $R(x, y)$ scope is within the universal quantifier scope whereas identity statement $x = y$ under the existential quantifier? But why?

Answer (score 4):

Statement 2. means "There is something which only stands in relation to itself". This should make it clear intuitively why the given structure is a model of the formula.
In terms of scope, since the existential quantifier comes first, $\exists$ has scope over $\forall$. So the $\forall$ statement only needs to apply for one element that is claimed to exist, which is satisfied by $v(x) = 5$. It is not said that every *pair* need to satisfy the biconditional, only that we can find at least one *"subject" term* (first argument to the relation) for which all "objects" (second argument) that it appears with are the same as the subject.

Comment: But then why reverse condition ∃xAy(R(y, x) ↔ x = y) is false if it also applies to at least one, like  <5, 5> ?

Comment: Because that formula now says that there is one *object* which only works with itself as a subject, which is false because 5 also appears with 1 and 2 as subjects.

Answer (score 2):

No issues with scopes: both quantifiers in 2. apply to the formula entire formula $(R(x,y) ↔ x = y)$.

The "solution" is $5$ because the only pairs that satisfy $x=y$ are $(1,1)$ and $(5,5)$. But for the first one we have that $R(1,2)$ holds while $1=2$ does not.

You can check it using a "pseudo truth table" entering as rows the pairs 5,1/5,2/.../5,5 and as columns $R(x,y)$ and $x=y$ respectively.

As you can see, we have that $R(5,5)$ and $5=5$ are both true, while $R(5,n)$ and $5=n$ are both false, for $n \ne 5$.

This means that $(R(5,y) ↔ 5 = y)$ is true for every value of $y$.

Comment: "both quantifiers in 2. have as scope the formula ((,)↔=)." $\exists$ also has scope over $\forall$, not just the biconditional formula.